Groovy Script : it gives me error while handling files more than 2G
I created a code to save all files into a zip file, but when my files reach 2GB, the code gives the error: 'Error executing the script: Required array length too large.' I tried to solve the problem, but it's not working.
this is the part of the script


private ZipOutputStream addZipEntry(ZipOutputStream zipOutput, File file, String path) {
    if (file.isDirectory() && !path.endsWith('/')) {
        path += "/"
    }
    logger.info("zipfile: added $path")
    ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(path)
    entry.time = file.lastModified()
    zipOutput.putNextEntry(entry)
    if (file.isFile()) {
        def fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file)
        zipOutput << fileInputStream
        fileInputStream.close()
    }
    return zipOutput
}

I need to solve this issue

Java normally only supports zip files under 2gb, according to this thread. It says that Java 7 supports zip64 mode, but no further information. In this thread, the library Apache Commons Compress is mentioned, which has Zip64 support if you scroll down.

Is that the full error message? Is there a stacktrace too?

error executing the script: Required array length too large @aled

It looks like Groovy chooses the wrong leftShift method for some reason. Try steering it to the right one by explicitly defining the variable type
        InputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file)

